# Laravel 10 helper functions VS code intelephense issues

Tags: visual-studio-code, helper, laravel-10, intelephense

I recently updated my laravel project from 9.x to 10.x.
Ever since the PHP intelephense extension in VS code is not able to find the global helper functions like `view()`, `app()`, `resolve()`, ... .
They get marked down as with for example `Undefined function 'App\Http\Controllers\Web\view'.intelephense(1010)`.

However the code still functions as normal.
Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: try [`composer require --dev barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper`](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper)

Comment: It looks like a package to improve autocompletion. Do you think it will help with the global helper functions? I was not using this package before in 9.x but vscode was able to find them at that point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer through [laracats](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/vscode-intelephense-issues-after-laravel-10x-upgrade):
I had to disable, reload and enable the intelephense extension.